# Get DATA with cURL in php with Bearer token

Tags: php, curl, bearer-token

How to download data in php via cURL with a Bearer token. The data retrieval method is GET.

```
public function ceidg(){

    $token = "***************************************";

    $qry_str = "?nip=8641792737";
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set query data here with the URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://dane.biznes.gov.pl/api/ceidg/firmy' . $qry_str); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
       ));
    $content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    
    var_dump($content);
}
```

The above code returns the string "0". Below is a screenshot from the documentation.
[Screen docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFHVW.jpg)

Link docs[PL]: https://akademia.biznes.gov.pl/images/HD-CEIDG-API-Hurtowni-Danych-Dokumentacja-dla-integratorow.pdf

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If a single string is returned, and not an error, I would assume that the server sent that string

Comment: curl the cli program has a default user-agent, it looks like `User-Agent: curl/7.75.0`, but libcurl does not have any default user-agent, and some websites blocks requests with no user-agent, perhaps that's the problem? set CURLOPT_USERAGENT to find out

Comment: also add CURLOPT_VERBOSE: ```$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
curl_exec($ch);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
echo $stderr;
``` and show the verbose log

Comment: the server should return an array in my opinion

Comment: log https://pastebin.com/rgfknA66

Comment: ok data is returned in string, i want this in array, how i can that?

Comment: Did You resolved this problem ? @DariuszPiechota